# Why the following jQuery works in Chrome but doesn't work in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div:nth-child(1)").animate({
    top: '+=585'
  }, 250);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div:nth-child(1)").animate({
      top: '-=585'
    }, 250);

  }, 250);

  $("div:nth-child(2)").animate({
    top: '-=585'
  }, 250);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div:nth-child(2)").animate({
      top: '+=585'
    }, 250);

  }, 250);

});
```

```html
<div>This is a cube</div>
<div>This is a triangle</div>
```

I have following two divs :

```
<div>This is a cube</div>
<div>This is a triangle</div>
```

And this is my jQuery that works when I run it in my browser but doesn't work when I test it in jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div:nth-child(1)").animate({ top: '+=585'}, 250);

  setTimeout(function() {
  $("div:nth-child(1)").animate({ top: '-=585'}, 250);

}, 250);

  $("div:nth-child(2)").animate({ top: '-=585'}, 250);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div:nth-child(2)").animate({ top: '+=585'}, 250);

}, 250);



});
```

Is there anything wrong with my jQuery? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: jQuery is cross browser compatible so I don't see why this wouldn't work in jsfiddle, perhaps you forgot to include the javascript file?

Comment: Mostly forgetting to include the jQuery file in jsFiddle.

Comment: Forget to add your CSS to the fiddle?

Comment: @samkauli, C'mon, man.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/y104ztry/1/

I wrapped the divs and set the wrapper to have `position:relative` and it works.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>This is a cube</div>
    <div>This is a triangle</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfqjbexe/1/